# Combining 3 tables in a sql query - Error column name is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am trying to combine 3 tables in one query with MySQL. However, I'm getting an error saying that the column name is ambiguous.

gndsale.AMOUNT is a column from another table named gndsale and the word AMOUNT is from gndtndr.

Error: Column 'amount' in field list is ambiguous

Here is my code:

```
SELECT g.ID
     , concat(emp.FIRSTNAME, ' ', emp.LASTNAME) Fullname
     , FORMAT(ROUND(SUM(s.AMOUNT), 2),0) as DECLARED
     , FORMAT(ROUND(SUM(amount), 2),0) as CALCULATED
     , `DATE`
     , `CHECK` 
  FROM gndtndr g 
  JOIN emp 
    ON emp.ID = g.ID
  JOIN gndsale s
    on g.ID= S.ID
 group 
    by EMPLOYEE
```

Comment: You should be able to just prefix the ambiguous column with its full name.  Gntndr.amount and that should disambiguate it.

Comment: It worked :D  
learning about join tables as of the moment hehe :)

Comment: Just remove the ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

Why don`t you use ROUND(SUM(gndtndr.AMOUNT), 2),0)

Comment: woah! that fixed it! Thanks :D 
I thought it would read it if its only ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT), 2),0).... but wow it worked :D

Comment: it would have worked with AMOUNT if you didn`t require both amounts from gndtndr and gndsale. Mysql got a bit confused because in one place you told him gndtndr.AMOUNT and on the other one just AMOUNT. It didnt know which amount to use hense the ambiguous error. So just always use the tablename infront of the column name, its a good practice :)